# Broken asp:image in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, safari

I am using ASP.net image tags like this.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("DeviceStatusFlag")%>' alt=''/>
```

Now when the ImageURL is blank then normally a broken image shows up in some browsers like Firefox but after using the `ält=''` these browsers show up nothing in place of images which is alright.
But in Safari browser i still see a ? mark image icon when the ImageURL is empty.

Also tried using this ,

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("DeviceStatusFlag")%>' AlternateText = '' GenerateEmptyAlternateText='true' />
```

But it does not work on Safari as well.

How to fix this for Safari ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I doubt it's an asp:image issue, if you replace it with a standard HTML img tag I can imagine it would do the same.

Clearly safari wants to render empty an src attribute that way. You could use JavaScript to hide it if it is empty, or add a transparent image instead of nothing.

Personally I don't think it's good practice to have an empty image src.

You could also use a div, with a background-image src, that would handle none as a setting.

Edit: And an alt tag is alternate text for images being turned off or for accessibility. Whilst that may change the behaviour in some browsers, that's not its intent.

Edit 2.

To hide your asp.net server control.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" visible="False" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("DeviceStatusFlag")%>' alt=''/>
```

Its probably easier for you to change both the `ImageUrl` and `Visible` on the server side.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server">
```

Such as:

```
Image6.Visible = False
Image6.ImageUrl = DeviceStatusFlag
```

OR

To get the actual rendered url of the `<img` tag being rendered.

Use

```
Image6.ClientID
```

You can embed that easily into the HTML as follows:

```
<script>

function setImageVisibility() {
  var imageID = "<%=Image6.ClientID%>",
      imageElement = document.getElementById(imageID);

  if(imageElement) {
     if(imageElement.src === "") {
           imageElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
     }
  }

}

setImageVisibility();

</script>
```

Comment: any clues on how can i use Javascript to hide it if empty. I tried but its does not find the "Image6" id.

Comment: Also i used the GenerateEmptyAlternateText property as directed in  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.generateemptyalternatetext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok so that's a wider question. Image6 is the ID on the server, that may or may not be the rendered ID. There is a server side property ClientID which will give you the id of the image. But then you'll need to get that id to the front end so you can access it. If the image is not going to change, simply mark it visible=false on the server if there is no source. Otherwise mention what language the backend is in, and asp.net forms/Mvc

Comment: Any sample code would help. i am noty sure i understand this clearly. i am new to Asp.net and Javascript.

Comment: Is it c# , asp.net forms? Or mvc or vb.net

Comment: Its written in vb.net

Comment: When i try that Image6.ClientID the browser says it cannot find variable Image6 !  Thanks for the detailed example though.  Is there a reason why it cannot find the Image6 variable?

Comment: The first half of the answer is vb.net, server side.